# How do we know EOS-Mainnet github is official?

Tags: mainnet, governance

I have seen this referenced as some sort of official account for EOS mainnet related repositories:

https://github.com/EOS-Mainnet

1. Is it actually official?
2. How do we know if this is official since this is not block.one?

Answer (score 1):

It is official.

See the link below.

https://medium.com/@eosnewyork/the-eos-mainnet-launch-security-software-testing-efd3f6c40f45

This article was written by EOS New York. EOS New York is the top 21 Block Producer on the EOS Mainnet Blockchain.

**I asked EOS New York about this content via Twitter.
EOS New York responded as follows.**

> Block on isn't official anymore. The EOS Mainnet repo is.

Comment: Are all the top 21 block producers using this repository? Is there some indication from at least two other parties that they are also using this?

Comment: yes, you can trust it

Comment: In fact, how do we know that we are not BP? I have to ask BP.

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate in your response on Nathan James's involvement in the repo as well as his involvement overall with the community.  Nathan was on this call and if you care to find the spot, Dan suggested the idea of working together on an API library for b1's wallet and Scatter.  From this, it can reasonably be assumed that Dan trusts and knows of Nathan. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWeebYd66vU

Comment: I have added the response of EOS New York to the answer.

Comment: Blockone recently released [EOS 1.0.6](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/tag/v1.0.6) 19 hours ago but [EOS-Mainnet last commit](https://github.com/EOS-Mainnet/eos/commits/master) is from 7 days ago.  So is the process that they pull the changes in from the EOSIO repo to the EOS-Mainnet repo first? And then presumably the Block Producers will update their systems?

Comment: If I run https://mainnet.eoscanada.com/v1/chain/get_info the server version shows `"server_version":"79651199"` which corresponds to the [EOS 1.0.6](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/tag/v1.0.6) commit hash from EOS.io repo.  So I'm confused how EOS-Mainnet can be the official repository if EOS Canada appears to be running 1.0.6 when EOS-Mainnet doesn't appear to have been updated to 1.0.6